# Python Pandas copy a set of cells within a dataframe based on a matching key

Tags: python, pandas, merge, copy-paste

My knowledge of Pandas is relatively limited, and I've accomplished a lot with a small foundation + all the help in SO.  This is the first time I've found myself at a dead end.

I'm trying to find the most efficient way to do the following:

I have a single df of ~150000 rows, with ~40 columns.

Here is a sample dataframe to work with for investigating a solution:

```
   UniqueID     CST  WEIGHT  VOLUME  PRODUCTIVITY
0  413-20012    3     123      12          1113
1  413-45365    1     889      75          6748
2  413-21165    8     554      13          4536
3  413-24354    1     387      35          7649
4  413-34658    2     121      88          2468
5  413-36889    4     105      76          3336
6  413-23457    5     355      42          7894
7  413-30089    5     146      10          9112
8  413-41158    5     453      91          4545
9  413-51015    9     654      66          2232
```

One of the columns is a unique ID, the remaining columns contain data corresponding to the object of that ID.  Example:

I've determined a merged-style relationship between the objects outside of the DF, and now need to paste data where that relationship exists, from a 'parent' ID to all of its 'child' IDs.

If I've determined that 413-23457 is the parent of 413-20012 and 413-21165, I then need to copy the values from the parent only in columns WEIGHT, VOLUME, and PRODUCTIVITY (but not UniqueID or CST) to the child objects.  I also determine that 413-41158 is the parent of 413-45365 and 413-51015.

I have to do this for many sets of these types of associations across the dataframe.

I've attempted to manipulate a lot of sample code for pasting between dataframes, but several of my requirements appear to be making it difficult to search for a useful enough sample.  I can also envision a way where I create objects of everything using .itterows(), and then matching and pasting accordingly in a loop.  But, having relegated to .iterrows() for past solutions, and noting how long it can take, I don't think I can apply that here and sustain it for larger datasets.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

Edit with additional content per suggested solution

If I rearrange the input dataframe to sort rows more randomly, the suggested answers do not really do the trick (my fault for not better reflecting the actual dataset to this test sample).

Starting Dataframe is:

```
   UniqueID     CST  WEIGHT  VOLUME  PRODUCTIVITY
0  413-20012    3     123      12          1113
1  413-45365    1     889      75          6748
2  413-21165    8     554      13          4536
3  413-24354    1     387      35          7649
4  413-34658    2     121      88          2468
5  413-36889    4     105      76          3336
6  413-23457    5     355      42          7894
7  413-30089    5     146      10          9112
8  413-41158    5     453      91          4545
9  413-51015    9     654      66          2232
```

Current suggested solution is:

```
parent_child_dict = {
    '413-51015': '413-41158',
    '413-21165': '413-23457',
    '413-45365': '413-41158',
    '413-20012': '413-23457'
}

(df.merge(df.UniqueID
           .replace(parent_child_dict),
         on='UniqueID',
         how='right')
   .set_index(df.index)
   .assign(UniqueID=df.UniqueID,
          CST=df.CST)
)
```

Resulting Dataframe is:

```
    UniqueID   CST  WEIGHT  VOLUME  PRODUCTIVITY
0  413-20012    3     387      35          7649
1  413-45365    1     121      88          2468
2  413-21165    8     105      76          3336
3  413-24354    1     355      42          7894
4  413-34658    2     355      42          7894
5  413-36889    4     355      42          7894
6  413-23457    5     146      10          9112
7  413-30089    5     453      91          4545
8  413-41158    5     453      91          4545
9  413-51015    9     453      91          4545
```

The results are not what was expected now that the rows are in a random order, and I don't understand some of what has happened.  Row with UniqueID 413-45365 was intended to mirror the data for 413-41158, but has some combination of data (121, 88, 2468) that does not exist in any of the other rows or even cells in the starting DF.

Comment: Do you have a DataFrame or Dict mapping the parents to the children?It would be helpful to add to your post.

Comment: Edit added.  Thank you.

Comment: First thing i would do is to get your parent-child relationship into a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

First thing i would do is to get your parent-child relationship into a dictionary. and then we can use `replace` and `merge`:

```
# create a dictionary of parent-child relationship
parent_child_dict = {}
for parent_id in parent_objects:
    children = get_merge(parent_id)
    for child in children:
        child_id = get_object_info(child)
        # update dict
        parent_child_dict[child_id] = parent_id

# parent_child_dict = {
#     '413-20012': '413-23457',
#     '413-21165': '413-23457',
#     '413-45365': '413-41158',
#     '413-51015': '413-41158'
# }

# merge and copy data back
(df.merge(df.UniqueID
           .replace(parent_child_dict),
         on='UniqueID',
         how='right')
   .set_index(df.index)
   .assign(UniqueID=df.UniqueID,
          CST=df.CST)
)
```

Output:

```
     UniqueID  CST  WEIGHT  VOLUME  PRODUCTIVITY
1   413-23457    5     355      42          7894
2   413-20012    3     355      42          7894
3   413-21165    8     355      42          7894
4   413-24354    1     387      35          7649
5   413-34658    2     121      88          2468
6   413-36889    4     105      76          3336
7   413-30089    5     146      10          9112
9   413-41158    5     453      91          4545
10  413-45365    1     453      91          4545
11  413-51015    9     453      91          4545
```

Comment: My first go at this returned an error:
ValueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
on this line:
----> 3             how='right').set_index(df_term.index).assign(UniqueID=df.UniqueID,

Comment: You probably use an older pandas that does not allow merge with series. Try to replace `df.Unique` with `df[['Unique']]`

Comment: Yep, you nailed it on the fix.  
The code is running, but the values that are getting copied into the Child ID rows do not match the parents (but they are new values)   Trying to determine where the newly pasted values are coming from.

Comment: Updating with an additional problem I'm having (apologies for delay, virus has deterred consistency).       
       
In application to my real dataset, this solution appear to not work because the arrangement of the rows in the dataframe is not in sequence.  In other words, the parent in this sample data set is in row1, then the children in row2 & row3.  In my actual dataset, the parent is in row400, then children in row2384 & row4823.  I'm not totally certain, but in trying to debug suspect this difference is the source of the problem.

Comment: Updated the original post with the new sample DF and the new results.